# Connect saved pffile to object from iOS to Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

I saved an image in Parse and after I call a function in the Cloud Code to save more data. I can pass the url and the file name. How do I connect in the Cloud function this picture to an object?

iOS code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo.image, 40);
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"photo.jpeg" data:imageData];

[imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        //Title
        NSString *titleString = @"title";
        //...

        NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    titleString,@"title",
                                    //...
                                    imageFile.url,@"photoUrl",
                                    imageFile.name,@"photoName",
                                    nil];

        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"savePost"
                           withParameters:@{@"data": dictionary}
                                    block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {
                                        //...
```

The Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("savePost", function(request, response) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var item = new Parse.Object("Post");
    item.set("title", request.params.data.title);
    //...

    item.set("photo", ???);

    //...
```

I do not want to save the data from the iOS app.
I just need to attach a photo already in Parse, of which I have the url, to the "Post" object.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done as you hope, because parse objects cannot be transmitted as parameters to `callFunctionInBackground`.  non-`PFFile`s can be sent as objectId's, leaving it to the cloud function to do the fetch, but no such facility exists for `PFFile`.

The only alternative I can see is to build the "Post" object on the client, along with setting its file property.  Save it from the client.  Anything else that you hoped to in the cloud function can be done afterwards, either in a cloud call or an afterSave handler for the Post.

Comment: But through the url I can not associate the file to the object?

Comment: No.  I checked for that before answering... something like fileWithURL would be what we'd want, but, sadly, no such thing that I can find.